# linking data from different elements in an xml file via xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, hyperlink, transformation

I have the following xml file in which each book element has three attributes: a @xml:id, an @author and an @info (comprised on '#'+'@xml:id'+'-ana' and is the same as the id of its corresponding genre element).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <Collection>
        <books>
            <book xml:id="d1" author="#e1" info="#d1-ana"/>
            <book xml:id="d2" author="#e2" info="#d2-ana"/>
            <book xml:id="d3" author="#e2" info="#d3-ana"/>
        </books>
        <genre xml:id="d1-ana"> autobiography </genre>
        <genre xml:id="d2-ana"> romance </genre>
        <genre xml:id="d3-ana"> horror </genre>
    </Collection>
    <authors>
        <author xml:id="e1">Author1</author>
        <author xml:id="e2">Author2</author>
    </authors>
</doc>
```

What I would like to do is for those cases in which @author has the same value (second and third book element with the @author value #e2), swap the order of the genres , meaning the genre element with the value horror comes first and the element with the value romance comes second, such as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <Collection>
        <books>
            <book xml:id="d1" author="#e1" info="#d1-ana"/>
            <book xml:id="d2" author="#e2" info="#d2-ana"/>
            <book xml:id="d3" author="#e2" info="#d3-ana"/>
        </books>
        <genre xml:id="d1-ana"> autobiography </genre>
        <genre xml:id="d3-ana"> horror </genre>
        <genre xml:id="d2-ana"> romance </genre>
    </Collection>
    <authors>
        <author xml:id="e1">Author1</author>
        <author xml:id="e2">Author2</author>
    </authors>
</doc>
```

I'm not quite sure how to compare those book elements and how to make the link to the genre elements (the @xml:id of each genre element is #+the value of @info of the book elements).

Comment: What would happen though, if author "#e1" also occurred twice, with info values of "#d1-ana" and "#d2-ana"?

Comment: What is the rule that says `horror` should come before `romance`? A static XSLT could obviously be written but I'm assuming there's an underlying rule you're trying to apply which isn't clear based on the sample XML (e.g. assuming you're matching `<book info="...">` to `<genre xml:id="...">`horror & romance, they each have 1 so what is the rule?)

Comment: I recommend researching the key declaration and key function constructs in the XSLT specification to see if it covers what you need. https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key